# IIS 7.5 Url Rewrite ignoring question mark

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule in IIS 7.5 Url Rewrite. What I'm trying to achieve is when someone clicks on a certain pdf file, I want them to be redirected to a form and then when they've filled out the form they get the pdf file which simply has a question mark. 
e.g. `?download=true` appended to the end of it that passes through the rewrite rule so:

`pdf/my-pdf-file.pdf will be redirected to go-to-this-file.aspx` (which would be a form)

then they're redirected to :

`pdf/my-pdfpfile.pdf?download=true` which the rewrite rule shouldn't pick up but it does which is my problem.

Here is my rule:

```
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="My PDF Rule">
                  <match url="^pdf/my-pdf-file.pdf$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/go-to-this-file.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Please can someone help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, you should check if the `{QUERY_STRING}` contains `download=true` and then don't redirect. Try this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="My PDF Rule">
                <match url="^pdf/my-pdf-file.pdf$" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="download=true" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/go-to-this-file.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this, it was driving me crazy.